# Sorting Access Form with unbound labels not working properly or consistently

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Form that displays fields directly from a table.

The procedure for Schl_name works (data type short text).  The Schlnolabel does not, data type Number.

In another form, School No sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.

Any logical reason why?

On to unbound labels, I have a on-click and on-double click events.

```
Private Sub Schl_name_Label_Click()
    Me.OrderBy = "Schl_name"                   ' <---- verified correct field name
    Me.OrderByOn = True
    End Sub

Private Sub Schl_name_Label_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.OrderBy = "Schl_name DESC"                    '  <---- verified correct field name
    Me.OrderByOn = True
End Sub

Private Sub SchlnoLabel_Click()
    Me.OrderBy = "Schl_no"                         '  <---- verified correct field name
    Me.OrderByOn = True
End Sub

Private Sub SchlnoLabel_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.OrderBy = "Schl_no DESC"                     '  <---- verified correct field name
    Me.OrderByOn = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorting numbers only works if they are actually of a number type. Otherwise, they will be sorted alphabetically, i.e., by the first digit, then by the second, etc. Is the form directly bound to  the table or is it bound to a query which possibly formats the number (which would convert it to a text)?

Comment: Nitpick terminology: labels are never "bound" because they do not hold data from table. Label can be "unassociated" - not connected to a data control.

Comment: Nitpick accepted :)

Comment: "Deleted this by accident":

As I said, it is bound to the table. I realize that numbers sort differently than alpha/text fields. to be clear, if I hit on School NO, label, either with a single or double-click either nothing happens or sometimes the sort changes. If I hit the School Name, it sorts according to clicks given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that distinguishing between single and double click might not be very reliable. I suggest always using a single click and then switching between ascending and descending on successive clicks.

```vb
Private isNameDesc As Boolean, isNoDesc As Boolean

Private Sub Schl_name_Label_Click()
    If isNameDesc Then
        Me.OrderBy = "Schl_name DESC"
    Else
        Me.OrderBy = "Schl_name"
    End If
    Me.OrderByOn = True
    isNameDesc = Not isNameDesc
    isNoDesc = False ' Always start in ascending order when switching between Name and No.
End Sub

Private Sub SchlnoLabel_Click()
    If isNoDesc Then
        Me.OrderBy = "Schl_no DESC"
    Else
        Me.OrderBy = "Schl_no"
    End If
    Me.OrderByOn = True
    isNoDesc = Not isNoDesc
    isNameDesc = False ' Always start in ascending order when switching between Name and No.
End Sub
```

To do so, I store the next sorting to be used in the Boolean variables for both name and number sorting.

Comment: Thank Olivier!

So, I pasted what you provided.  Schl_Name_Label works (only if I l click after the mid-point of the label (which is a width of 2.125".

SchlnoLabel, (which has a width of 0.25") just doesn't work.

Comment: Access assosciates events with controls by their name.  if clicking on schlnoLabel isn't working it's click code signature might be wrongly named.  Try right clicking the control and re-creating the click event, and then paste the code from inside the current click event into the new click event.

Comment: Mazoula, attempted what you said.  even removed event, renamed label, changed the order of the column, no joy.  Very weird...

Comment: If the event is wired up correctly, then you will see the label name in the left drop -down above the VBA editor and the Click event name in the right drop-down when the cursor is in Sub SchlnoLabel_Click. If not, you can do it the other way round. Select the label in the left drop-down, then `Click` appears in the right one and the Sub is created automatically. Also, set a Break-Point in SchlnoLabel_Click to see whether it is called or not.

Comment: Made sure special keys was check in option.  reopened database, reset the vba code (used me.orderby="Schl_no" and orderbyon...  Clicked on Orderby and hit F9.  Closed Query, reopened and nothing.

Comment: On a lark, I ran in VBA window Compile.  no errors

Comment: I tried a breakpoint on a different field, and it worked.

Comment: Does a breakpoint in Sub `SchlnoLabel_Click` work? If not, then this name does not match the label name + "_Click". Why does `Schl_name_Label` have underscores but not `SchlnoLabel`?

Comment: To your first question, no it doesn't, but the labels match.
to your second, I attempted to try different solutions.

Comment: Copy the content of SchlnoLabel_Click to notepad. Then delete it from your code. Then re-create it by selecting the label in the drop-down above the code (don't create the Sub manually!). This ensures that the name is correct and that the Sub is linked to the label.

Comment: BTW, on another form, I have Sch_no_Label and it doesn't work either, but Schl_name_Label does....

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT... I am an idiot.  There was the form title overlapping Schl_no and part of  Schl_name....  I haven't programmed Access in over a decade and thought it was in the "background"  THANK YOU OLIVIER and others, sorry to waste your time.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that you solved the problem.